# NestJS dependency injection and TransformPipe

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I've created a module A, that has an exported provider `AService`. Module B imports module A and has an exported `BTransformPipe` provider, that uses `AService`. Now, my understanding is, that when I import module B in module C, I should be able to use `BTransformPipe` in controller declared in module C, without declaring any further dependencies, but NestJS fails to inject `AService` in `BTransformPipe` used in module C. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhancers don't really go in the `providers` array nor do they get resolved from there. If you use `BTransformPipe` in `CModule`, then `CModule` needs to have access to all of the dependencis of `BTransformPipe`. To make this easy to keep track of, your `BModule` can have `AModule` in the `imports` and the `exports` and then you'll just need to have `BModule` in the `imports` of the module where you're wanting to use the `BTransformPipe`.

Comment: That makes sense, do you know if it's pointed out somewhere in the docs? Or maybe to know such details I'd just have to take a look into the implementation?